# Allow folder access to an external employee

Tags: external-users, license

I have a full 365 license and I want to create a folder for external employees so that they can store and share their documents. Is there a way to do it without having to pay for extra full licenses?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is possible. Take a look at this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-external-sharing-for-your-sharepoint-online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85

Comment: As far as I know, users with a Microsoft account can be invited to ant SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutly, that is indeed what external sharing / extranets is intended for.

This article is a great primer :
https://sharepointmaven.com/setup-external-users-sharepoint/

However be aware that employees in your company can not be considered external users from a licensing point of view.